# Pass future date to format-time-string

Tags: format-time-string

I want to be able to evaluate something like `(format-time-string "%A")`, but have it return tomorrow's date instead of today's (or next week's, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To generate the TIME argument you can use `date-to-time`.  Note that you need to supply a time even if you just care about the date.  E.g.:

```
(date-to-time "2023-04-27 00:00")
```